# select2 jquery: On createTag, specify the value of the new tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a way to customize the value of a new tag? For example I want to create something like this:
`<option value="myCustomValue">The New Created Tag</option>`

I'm trying to do this, but is not working, and I can't find something on the documentación about this:

```
        createTag: function (params) {
            var term = $.trim(params.term);

            if (term === '') {
                return null;
            }

            return {
                id: term,
                text: term,
                newTag: true, // add additional parameters,
                value: "myCustomValue"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with the documentation, the way to do it is this one:

```
createTag: function(params) { return { id: "myCustomValue", text: params.term }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Select2 can dynamically create new options from text input by the user in the search box. This feature is called "tagging". To enable tagging, set the tags option to true.

```
$('#example').select2({  
    tags: true
});
```

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/qrdvjzyp/